# AWS Quicksight calculated fields gives incorrect result for simple division

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have a dataset with fields `targeted` and `opens` and I need to add calculated field `opens per targeted` which essentially means doing simple devision of those 2 values.

My calculated field is as follows

```
{opens}/{targeted}
```

but then displaying simple table with values they are completely incorrect

[image: example of incorrect calculations]

If I try any other operator like `+` `*` etc calculations are correct.

I'm completely out of ideas on how to debug this. I've simplified the dataset to just columns of targeted and opens, can't get any simpler.

Comment: Maybe try 1.0*{opens}/{targeted}

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem, I fixed it by wrapping the columns with the `sum()` function. Like this:

```
sum({opens})/sum({targeted})
```

Comment: This solved the problem I was facing too. I am not sure about this behavior of QS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make AWS understand that you are working with float numbers.

```
1.0*{opens}/{targeted}
```

if still not working try also

```
(1.0*{opens})/({targeted}*1.0)
```

it should give you the desired output (not tested, let me know if it doesnt work)

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with a field name `target`.
It is working with every other field name appropriately except this one.

When I am wrapping this `target` field in curly braces in calculated field and when I am checking the calcualted formula again by editing the calcualted field the curly braces is removed automatically for `target` field.

Finally I changed the name of this field from `target` to `target_val` it worked.